# Postgresql improve select performance/parallelism in huge table

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a huge table (> 3000 million rows, totaling 3 TB) using Postgres 9.5 defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_events
(
    user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    datetime BIGINT NOT NULL,
    field1 VARCHAR,
    field2 VARCHAR,
    field3 VARCHAR,
    field4 VARCHAR,
    field5 VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT user_events_user_id_datetime_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id, datetime)
);

alter table user_events set (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=10);
```

I need to query this table roughly 2000 times per second but I'm not being able to parallelize enough (I'm reaching approx half that).

Using the following prepared statement, I get a reasonable (I suppose) response time:

```
PREPARE getact AS select * from user_events where user_id = $1 order by datetime limit 1000;

explain analyze EXECUTE getact('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.70..1495.10 rows=367 width=878) (actual time=0.028..0.044 rows=4 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using user_events_user_id_datetime_pk on user_events  (cost=0.70..1495.10 rows=367 width=878) (actual time=0.026..0.034 rows=4 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'::text)
 Execution time: 0.073 ms
```

Some additional notes:

- The content wasn't loaded in an orderly manner so datetime won't be
  physically ordered increasingly but from now on it will.
- The table is mostly append only
- We expect the table to grow at most a %50 more in the long term.

At this point I'm looking for any **configuration suggestion**. I know I had scaling options like a readonly replica or sharding, but would like to avoid that as much as possible for now.

Would executing `CLUSTER` work in this case? It would seems like the most part of the cost is in the index scanning, so I'd guess it won't, but I don't know (and testing it is really expensive).

Some more information:

- There are multiple threads writing (mostly appending) at the same rate that needs to be read
- Though the times described with the prepared statement are real, I've seen results ranging from < 1 ms to > 100ms

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (slowest) result

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE user_id = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using user_events_user_id_datetime_pk on user_events  (cost=0.70..1495.10 rows=367 width=878) (actual time=3.336..1162.936 rows=1518 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=5 read=1532
 Planning time: 0.071 ms
 Execution time: 1164.926 ms
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE user_id = 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy';
```

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using user_events_user_id_datetime_pk on user_events  (cost=0.70..1495.10 rows=367 width=878) (actual time=18.890..953.809 rows=1269 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=5 read=1282 dirtied=107
 Planning time: 0.105 ms
 Execution time: 955.590 ms
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't reach an answer for the issue (due to time constraints), I think that the most useful tip to remark is:

Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ...` on many queries (with **different** values) to try to understand what is happening. In my case, this put back `CLUSTER` as a possible optimization option.

What I would do if I had the time to try to optimize the table:

1. Change the indexed values for the smallest possible. In my case, that would mean changing the `user_id` from `VARCHAR`to `UUID`.
2. Execute [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html) to reduce the number of pages fetched.

Comment: On additional note, CLUSTER requires at least (table size + idx size) **free space** to work. So, in a huge table like my case, this is not a valid alternative. So, as final remark, in my case it would be a better idea to try to load the information in an orderly manner to minimize the performance issues described.